# using laravel echo with laravel lighthouse to listen for subscriptions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I'm running into some issues using laravel echo on a stand-alone vue3 app and a laravel api.

In my frontend I have the following configured:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_GRAPHQL_URL,
});

const echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY.toString(),
  cluster: 'eu',
  forceTLS: true,
  disableStats: true,
  authEndpoint: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_GRAPHQL_URL + `/subscriptions/auth`,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization:
        'Bearer ' + CookieManager.get(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE?.toString() ?? '') ??
        undefined,
    },
  },
});

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export const subscriptionClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([authLink, createLighthouseSubscriptionLink(echo), httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

which is than loaded into the `main.ts` file

```
app.provide(DefaultApolloClient, subscriptionClient);
```

Now, if I where to make any normal graphql queries that don't involve subscriptions they run as expected. but, if I run a subscription or listen to an event broadcasted from laravel itself I run into the following issue I receive a 403 forbidden error e.g. :

create a test event :

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('test');
    }
}
```

create a test channel :

```
Broadcast::channel('test', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

Listen to this channel on the frontend

```
echo.private('test').listen('TestEvent', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

following error occurs :

```
Pusher :  : ["Error: Unable to retrieve auth string from channel-authorization endpoint - received status: 403 from http://localhost:8000/graphql/subscriptions/auth. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authorizing-users/"]
```

I tried searching for some docs on how to use the graphql subscriptions AND the normal laravel broadcasting together but honestly after hours of searching my brain has melted.

Answer (score 0):

The subscription authentication endpoint can only authenticate GraphQL subscriptions.
It cannot authenticate normal broadcast events.

Comment: I see, so normal laravel events should be handled like normal?